# How to Print Completed Web Form

Tags: forms, printing

This is probably very simple but here goes - I need to put a form on my site for the users to fill in, however I need them to be able to print the completed form and mail it as opposed to submit it to me elctronically.

I have no problem creating the form, however the normal print command prints just the form without what the user has filled in, therefore is it possible to send the completed form to the printer?

Suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this having them submit the form, and then rendering the information cleanly so that the resulting page could be printed.

If you are dead set on having them print without first submitting the form, look at this question: [Printing HTML Form using window.print()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18316323/printing-html-form-using-window-print)